# Почему нельзя просто освободить память занимаемую элементами?

Tags: c++

Прелюдия: если производить освобождение динамической памяти через операцию `delete[]`, то сначала вызовутся деструкторы объектов в этом динамическом массиве, а затем освободиться память непосредственно самим оператором (ссылаюсь на книгу Саттера)

Вопрос: почему нельзя просто освободить память? Просто сказать что она бесхозная, и можем ее использовать как хотим (не вызывать деструкторы)

Comment: Полный ответ уже содержится в вопросе: потому, что в этом случае не будут вызваны деструкторы объектов + память, которую они занимают, не освободится.

Comment: Работайте с структурами или простыми типами (int ,long), просто `malloc` - взяли, `free`- просто освободили

Comment: Возможно, поможет: http://pcdev.ru/cpp-memory-management-part2/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если кратко описывать принцип работы `delete`:

1. Вызываем деструктор объекта (если есть)
2. Говорим, что память "бесхозная" и доступна для выделения.

После этого работа с "удаленным" объектом влечет за собой неопределенное поведение.

Так вот. Как я понял, ваш вопрос в том, зачем нужен деструктор, так?

Если провести параллель - представьте, что вы - повар. Работаете на кухне. Тут вам говорит босс, что вы уволены. Вы просто уйдете. Но на кухне включен газ, на нем кипит вода в кастрюльках. И что с газом теперь будет? Кто его отключит?

Поэтому вы выполняете уборку, прежде чем уйти. Отключаете газ, моете кастрюли (хотя если вы вспыльчивый, то программы у вас могут быть горяченькие, хе-хе).

А теперь вернёмся к c++.
Представьте себе класс:

```
class string {
    char *data;
public: 
    string() {
        data = new char[10];
    }
};
```

Создали класс, при создании в конструкторе создали дополнительный массивчик `char`. Поработали с классом, а теперь решили его удалить. Вызываем `delete`, память под объект освобождается (по сути, лишь память под указатель `char *`). И все хорошо, все счастливы.

А вот и нет! Кто же будет освобождать память, выделенную под `char[10]`? Никто! Поэтому для такого класса нужно написать деструктор:

```
~string() {
    delete[] data;
}
```

Теперь, когда вы решите удалить ваш объект `string`, сначала вызовется его деструктор, в котором очистится память, которую этот объект выделял. И не будет утечек.

С оператором `delete[]` смысл тот же, только деструкторы он вызывает не у одного объекта, а сразу у кучи.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74056/discussion-on-answer-by-selya------).